# Error when post file url have backspace

Tags: php, ajax

I post ajax data with params no backspace, it's work ok

```
images/BLADE-230-S/MH-230S080AB_l.jpg
```

But it not woking when I post with params have backspace

```
images/BLADE 230 S/MH-230S080AB_l.jpg
```

Help me, how ideas for this bug.
Many thanks

Comment: post your code pls

Comment: Isn't *backspace* is keyboard button to delete previous element from cursor? Use `%20` instead of space - URL encode your params. But I doubt it's the actual problem. Maybe your backend does not decode properly params and searches for `BLADE%20230%20S` instead?

Answer (score -1):

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) can make help in this case. Use like this:

```
urlencode('images/BLADE 230 S/MH-230S080AB_l.jpg');
```